# Not able to install SQL Server on an EC2 instance using a cloud formation script

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to launch an EC2 instance and Install SQL Server on it using AWS CF.
I have done the following things:

```
1. Created a powershell script to download executables for SQL Server.
2. Creating a .bat file to trigger installation once the installation is completed.
3. Once the instance gets created the file is downloaded and installation should start.
```

But i am getting a waitcondition timeout error.

my code

https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/zmanda1/piece.txt

Thanks & Regards,
Shantanu

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you have signaled your wait condition that your instance is completed.  You must signal your wait condition from your instance with the cfn-signal command.  See the [AWS documentation](http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-signal.html).

I cannot say whether or not there's something else wrong that may prevent the template from working, but you either need to signal the start of your instance with cfn-signal, or remove the wait condition entirely.